# Deploy Next.Js React App to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-web-app-service

I created an Azure App Service running Node 16 on Linux. I ran `next build` and moved all files and folders that were generate inside the `.next` folder to the Azure App Service. Unfortunately, the app isn't running. I feel like I am missing some configurations or startup commands on Azure to successfully run the app. I would appreciate some help from somone that was able to deploy a NextJs app on Azure App Services. All other articles that I found were not able to solve my problem. This might be due to changes on the Azure platform.

Comment: What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: It is just saying "Application Error". It's the default error message if the application isn't able to run.

Comment: Turn on [application logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs#enable-application-logging-linuxcontainer) , it helps you in identifying the issue

Comment: Turned it on and can read the following error: `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` ... `/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next`

Comment: Do I need to copy the `node_modules` folder to Azure as well? It is nowhere mentioned in the NextJs docs

Comment: what is the startup comamnd you are using. Update to `/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next start -p $PORT`